# working with mvc3 and MySQL using connector 6.4.3

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MS visual web developer 2010 express.
i'm trying to get it work with MySql server. 
I've downloaded the net connector 6.4.3 and I can see mysql entry in the reference.
But when trying use this connector by adding a new connection to the database explorer I don't  see the MySql as an option among the other DBs in the list.

In some posts I've seen that people have changed the web.config file to get things working, but according to the documentation  net connector 6.4.3 the connection should be added and edited via adding a new data source via the database explorer.

What am i missing here?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I learned it all from this tutorial http://www.vbmysql.com/articles/vbnet-mysql-tutorials/the-vbnet-mysql-tutorial-part-3